# How to Run Tunefs on Root Filesystem in FreeBSD?

Tags: filesystems, mount, freebsd, acl, root-filesystem

I want to enable ACLs for a FreeBSD 11 system. According to the [FreeBSD Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/doc/5.3-RELEASE/usr/share/doc/handbook/fs-acl.html) this can be done in two ways:

1. By using a mount option -- `mount -o acls`
2. By modifying a superblock -- `tunefs -a enable`

It says that it is preferable to use the second option, because:

> The mount-time ACLs flag cannot be changed by a remount (mount(8) -u), only by means of a complete umount(8) and fresh mount(8). This means that ACLs cannot be enabled on the root file system after boot. It also means that you cannot change the disposition of a file system once it is in use.
>
> Setting the superblock flag will cause the file system to always be mounted with ACLs enabled even if there is not an fstab entry or if the devices re-order. This prevents accidental mounting of the file system without ACLs enabled, which can result in ACLs being improperly enforced, and hence security problems.

From the tunefs [man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=tunefs&sektion=8):

> The tunefs    utility is designed to change the dynamic parameters of a UFS
>        file system which affect the layout policies.  The tunefs utility cannot
>        be run on an active file system.  To change an active file system, it
>        must be downgraded to read-only or unmounted.

The problem is that rootfs (/) can't be unmounted.

How can I run tunefs on the root filesystem?

Comment: Is it out of question booting from another filesystem/USB?

Comment: Yeah, it's running a server to which I don't have physical access.

Comment: Reboot the Server and set your flags for the Filesystem. Perhaps some tweaking is needed to fit your needs. I would have just comment on your question but i do not have enough reputation to do that. <https://gist.github.com/bdrewery/1826994>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can forcibly remount the filesystem read-only:

```
mount -fur /
tunefs -a enable /
reboot
```

The `reboot` step seems to be neccessary: first, remounting read-write (`mount -uw /`) doesn't pick up the ACL enable flag, and second, remounting read-only will break everything that wanted to write to disk (eg syslogd), so you're better off just rebooting at that point.